# How to download pdf file that generated in laravel from react js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, pdf

I have a Laravel application that generates PDF files using a specific endpoint. The PDF generation on the server side is working fine, and I can access the generated PDF by making a request to the relevant Laravel route.

Now, I'm trying to implement a feature in my React JS frontend to download this generated PDF. What would be the standard approach or best practices for initiating and handling the download of a PDF from a Laravel backend in a React JS frontend?

I've looked into various methods, but I'm not sure about the optimal way to handle file downloads from React JS, especially when dealing with a Laravel backend. Any guidance, code examples, or recommended libraries would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code how i generate pdf:

```
public function mostReservationReport (Request $request) {
        $year = $request->input('year');

        $customer = DB::table('reservasi as r')
        ->join('customer as c', 'r.id_customer', '=', 'c.id')
        ->join('transaksi as t', 'r.id', '=', 't.id_reservasi')
        ->select('c.nama', DB::raw('COUNT(r.id) as jumlah'), DB::raw('SUM(t.total_pembayaran) as total'))
        ->whereYear('t.created_at', $year)
        ->groupBy('c.nama')
        ->orderByDesc('jumlah')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();

        $now = now();

        $no = 1;
        $total = 0;
        foreach($customer as $data){
            $data->no = $no;
            $no++;
            $total += $data->total;
        }

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('top-five-customer', compact('year', 'customer', 'now', 'total'));
        return $pdf->stream('top-five-customer.pdf');
    }
```

This is the laravel blade for pdf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Top 5 customer with the most reservasions</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@3.9.4/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <style>
      .table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .td, .th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      .table-borderless {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border: none !important;
      }

      .td-borderless {
        border: none !important;
      }

      .th-borderless {
        border: none !important;
      }

      .text-right {
        text-align: right;
      }

      .text-center {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .text-bold {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      
      .w-10 {
        width: 10%;
      }

      .w-20 {
        width: 20%;
      }

      .w-30 {
        width: 30%;
      }

      .w-60 {
        width: 60%;
      }

      .w-80 {
        width: 400px;
      }

      .w-90 {
        width: 500px;
      }

      .w-full {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .center {
          text-align: center;
      }

      .center img {
          margin: auto;
          display: block;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <img src="{{ public_path('storage/gah.jpg') }}" alt="logo">
    <h6>Jl. P. Mangkubumi No.18, Yogyakarta 55233</h6>
    <hr style="margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
    <h4 style="text-align:center; font-weight: 900;">TOP 5 CUSTOMER WITH MOST RESERVATIONS REPORT</h5>
    <p style="text-align:left">Year : {{$year}}</p>
    
    <div className="overflow-x-auto" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <table class="table w-full">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="th">No</th>
            <th class="th">Customer's Name</th>
            <th class="th">Reservation Count</th>
            <th class="th">Payment Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($customer as $item)
          <tr>
            <th class="th">{{$item->no}}</th>
            <td class="td">{{$item->nama}}</td>
            <td class="td">{{$item->jumlah}}</td>
            <td class="td">Rp {{ number_format($item->total, 2,'.', ',') }}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-bold">Total</td>
            <td class="text-bold">Rp {{ number_format($total, 2,'.', ',') }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="w-80"></td>
          <td class="w-10">Dicetak tanggal {{$now}}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To download a PDF generated by a Laravel backend in a React JS frontend, you can use the following approach. Assuming you have a function downloadPDF triggered on some user action:

```
const invoice = async() => {
        const printLoading = document.getElementById('print_loading')
        printLoading.showModal()

        try{
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/invoice/'+id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    Accept: 'application/pdf'
                },
                responseType: 'blob'
            })
            
            printLoading.close()
            const blob = await response.blob()
            console.log(response)
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            const link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href = url
            link.download = 'invoice.pdf'
            document.body.appendChild(link)
            link.click()
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        }
        catch(error){
            printLoading.close()
            console.log(error)
        }

    }
```